# for-loop doesn't work in android try-catch block

Tags: java, android, for-loop, try-catch, realm

I am making database of my school's building and classroom with Realm. But, 'for-loop' in try-catch doesn't work:

```
public void startCheckRealm() {
    // Writing DataBase with Realm
    try {
        Log.d("Realm", "Init");
        InitializeAPI.init_BuildingRoom(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        Log.d("Realm", "Complete");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Trying to check the Database whether it is right or wrong
    try {
        Log.d("Realm Test", "2nd Try Catch");

        Realm.init(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

        RealmResults<BuildingList> buildingLists = realm.where(BuildingList.class).findAllSorted("buildingCode");

        int totalNumber = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < buildingLists.size(); i++) {
            Log.d("For", "index = " + i);
            RealmResults<RoomList> rooms = buildingLists.get(i).getRoomList().sort("roomCode");

            String BuildingName = buildingLists.get(i).getBuildingName();
            String BuildingCode = buildingLists.get(i).getBuildingCode();

            for(int idx = 0; idx < rooms.size(); idx++) {
                totalNumber++;
                String RoomCode = rooms.get(idx).getRoomCode();
                String RoomName = rooms.get(idx).getRoomName();

                Log.d("Realm Test", "Number :: " + String.valueOf(totalNumber) + "   BuildingCode :: " + BuildingCode + "\t\t BuildingName :: " + BuildingName + "\t\t RoomCode :: " + RoomCode + "\t\t RoomName :: " + RoomName);
            }
        }
        Log.d("Realm Test", "2nd Try Catch Complete + " + String.valueOf(totalNumber));
    } catch(RealmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In the first try-catch, the method, which does making database, is complete without Exception. I was curious whether this database is right or wrong.

So, in 2nd try-catch, I was trying to check realm files with queries.

The problem is "for-loop" doesn't work in 2nd try-catch. Below snippet is my logcat.

```
D/Realm: Init
I/System.out: bdList getLength :: 52
I/System.out: roomList getLength :: 2376
D/Realm: Complete
D/Realm Test: 2nd Try Catch
D/Realm Test: 2nd Try Catch Complete + 0
```

**I want to check my realm data with Log but, doesn't work as you can see.**

If there is no problem, the logcat shows lots of my building and room lists and ends with "D/Realm Test: 2nd Try Catch Complete + 2376".

Could you explain the reason why it doesn't work? I cannot understand the reason why it doesn't work even though there is no Exception.

Comment: buildingLists is empty?

Comment: Your query is most likely wrong, and returns zero records. I'm not in the least bit familiar with Realm, but can you investigate the database by hand to see if the records really do exist?

Comment: @Jerry06 Maybe Nope. InitializeAPI.init_BuildingRoom(getActivity().getApplicationContext()); method in 1st try-catch makes 52 buildingLists. You can see the Length of buildingList in logcat.

Comment: @KenY-N if I call method 2 times in a row, it said "the primary key of buildingList is duplicated". (Of course, I call method 2 times.) That means, my writing database in realm seems right, isn't it?

Comment: try put Log.d("buildingLists.size() ", buildingLists.size()); before your loop

Comment: @KenY-N And 2nd period of calling methods, it shows lots of logs as I expected. but, the problem is it doesn't work at the 1st time.

Comment: Did you commit your `init_BuildingRoom()` transactions correctly? Perhaps you are missing some kind of flush leaving the data unwritten until you exit the app then run again? Perhaps you could post the `init_BuildingRoom` code?

Comment: @Jerry06 Ew.. my logcat said "buildingLIsts.size() is 0".. I think there is some mistake in my codes :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While in your use-case this doesn't pose a problem, when you're iterating a RealmResults inside a transaction, the results are live in every version <= 0.88.3 and >= 3.0.0.

So in that case,

```
    RealmResults<BuildingList> buildingLists = realm.where(BuildingList.class).findAllSorted("buildingCode");
    for(int i = 0; i < buildingLists.size(); i++) {
        BuildingList buildingList = buildingLists.get(i); // <-- !!!
```

will fail (it will skip every second item!)

So you should use iterators instead (3.0.0+! on <= 0.88.3 you'd do reverse iteration)

```
    RealmResults<BuildingList> buildingLists = realm.where(BuildingList.class).findAllSorted("buildingCode");
    for(BuildingList buildingList : buildingLists) { // <-- !!!
```

The reason why this works is because iterators by default create a new snapshot collection (3.0.0+), and iterating by index on a snapshot also works

```
OrderedRealmCollection<BuildingList> snapshot = buildingLists.createSnapshot();
for(int i = 0; i < ...
```

Comment: Wow.. I read "snapshot" in realm official documents  a month ago but, I didn't catch it exactly. (Of course, also, I didn't think that "I should use it") I have to read about that. :) Thanks to give me new study things!!!

Answer (score 1):

Simple: there is no exception thrown; and you only have your print statements **inside** the loop.

Thus the one and only conclusion: at that point in time when your for loops are executed, the corresponding list is **empty**. Therefore the loop body is not entered; nothing gets printed. And that has *nothing* to do with the fact that this loop is within a try-catch block.

That is all there is to this. So, the direct answer is: print the list size **directly** in front of the loop to avoid such surprises.

(of course, the *interesting* part is to understand what happens to the list which seems to be non-empty earlier on - but in order to debug that, you would have to add *more* of your code).

Comment: Yep.  you were right. The list size was 0. But, I am curious why my list is not updated with above methods, named "InitializeAPI.init_BuildingRoom(getActivity().getApplicationContext());"... I should study more about my project :(

Comment: Sure. Beyond that: you can upvote helpful content; and in case you find one of the answers "answering" the question, please consider accepting. Personally, I would suggest that you step back, create a [mcve] of that "list is not empty and then turns empty" problem and write up a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Two inputs:
1.Haven't used realm but looks like the syntax for getting sorted entriesis a bit different [Official documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#sorting)

2.If the above point is wrong than from your code it looks like *buildingList* size is zero. Have you tried checking the size?

Let me know the results.

Comment: I think the sorting goes well. But, you were right BuildingList.size() was 0. My logcat said "buildingLIsts.size() is 0" :(

Comment: try replacing the read syntax with what my suggested link says. Let me know. Kindly upvote, if helpful thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try logging your catch block. Chances are the rest of the code including the loop didn't complete because your app was caught with the Exception.

Comment: I was coding "e.printStackTrace();" in catch block. Isn't it over? Is there any more work to print the error log in my logcat?

Comment: Use Log.e(TAG, "Message", e);

Answer (score 0):

You should debug `buildingLists.size();` before `for loop`

```
Log.d("Building List Size ", buildingLists.size()+"");
```

In that case you can find the value of `buildingLists.size();`